# How to select parent checkboxes when no way to edit HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-lists

First of all I want to say that I have searched for possible solutions and have found similar questions. But the problem is that I have no control over HTML part.

List is generated by wp_types plugin dynamicly, so, I cannot add custom classes to HTML in order to change particular value with JS.

Here is my code:

```html
<ul class="wpt-form-set wpt-form-set-checkboxes wpt-form-set-checkboxes-event-type" data-level="0"><li class="tax-corporate-events tax-event-type-52">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-30-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-30-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="52" data-parent="-1" data-value="CORPORATE EVENTS" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-30-1438779193">CORPORATE EVENTS</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-children-of-52"><ul class="wpt-form-set-children wpt-form-set-children-level-1" data-level="1"><li class="tax-after-dinner-shows tax-event-type-87">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-31-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-31-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="87" data-parent="52" data-value="AFTER DINNER SHOWS" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-31-1438779193">AFTER DINNER SHOWS</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-award-ceremonies tax-event-type-92">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-32-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-32-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="92" data-parent="52" data-value="AWARD CEREMONIES" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-32-1438779193">AWARD CEREMONIES</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-background-music tax-event-type-86">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-33-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-33-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="86" data-parent="52" data-value="BACKGROUND MUSIC" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-33-1438779193">BACKGROUND MUSIC</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-comperes tax-event-type-91">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-34-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-34-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="91" data-parent="52" data-value="COMPERES" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-34-1438779193">COMPERES</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-dance-the-night-away tax-event-type-89">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-35-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-35-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="89" data-parent="52" data-value="DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-35-1438779193">DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-exhibitions tax-event-type-84">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-36-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-36-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="84" data-parent="52" data-value="EXHIBITIONS" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-36-1438779193">EXHIBITIONS</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-mix-mingle tax-event-type-90">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-37-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-37-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="90" data-parent="52" data-value="MIX &amp; MINGLE" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-37-1438779193">MIX &amp; MINGLE</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-product-launches tax-event-type-85">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-38-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-38-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="85" data-parent="52" data-value="PRODUCT LAUNCHES" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-38-1438779193">PRODUCT LAUNCHES</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-wow-factor tax-event-type-88">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-39-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-39-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="88" data-parent="52" data-value="WOW FACTOR" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-39-1438779193">WOW FACTOR</label>
</li></ul></li>

<li class="tax-private-parties tax-event-type-83">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-40-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-40-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="83" data-parent="-1" data-value="PRIVATE PARTIES" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-40-1438779193">PRIVATE PARTIES</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-children-of-83"><ul class="wpt-form-set-children wpt-form-set-children-level-1" data-level="1"><li class="tax-chill-out tax-event-type-101">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-41-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-41-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="101" data-parent="83" data-value="CHILL OUT" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-41-1438779193">CHILL OUT</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-party-band tax-event-type-99">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-42-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-42-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="99" data-parent="83" data-value="PARTY BAND" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-42-1438779193">PARTY BAND</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-tribute-theme tax-event-type-98">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-43-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-43-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="98" data-parent="83" data-value="TRIBUTE THEME" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-43-1438779193">TRIBUTE THEME</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-walk-around-acts tax-event-type-102">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-44-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-44-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="102" data-parent="83" data-value="WALK AROUND ACTS" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-44-1438779193">WALK AROUND ACTS</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-wow-factor tax-event-type-100">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-45-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-45-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="100" data-parent="83" data-value="WOW FACTOR" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-45-1438779193">WOW FACTOR</label>
</li></ul></li>

<li class="tax-wedding tax-event-type-53">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-46-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-46-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="53" data-parent="-1" data-value="WEDDING" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-46-1438779193">WEDDING</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-children-of-53"><ul class="wpt-form-set-children wpt-form-set-children-level-1" data-level="1"><li class="tax-ceremony tax-event-type-93">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-47-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-47-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="93" data-parent="53" data-value="CEREMONY" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-47-1438779193">CEREMONY</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-drinks-reception tax-event-type-94">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-48-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-48-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="94" data-parent="53" data-value="DRINKS RECEPTION" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-48-1438779193">DRINKS RECEPTION</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-evening-party tax-event-type-95">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-49-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-49-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="95" data-parent="53" data-value="EVENING PARTY" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-49-1438779193">EVENING PARTY</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-mix-mingle tax-event-type-97">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-50-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-50-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="97" data-parent="53" data-value="MIX &amp; MINGLE" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-50-1438779193">MIX &amp; MINGLE</label>
</li>

<li class="tax-sangeet tax-event-type-96">
<input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-51-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-51-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="96" data-parent="53" data-value="SANGEET" class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox"><label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-51-1438779193">SANGEET</label>
</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I need parent checkbox to be selected when any of child checkboxes is selected.

And is there any way to make it work even if there will be more event types added by wordpress?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each input is linked to the parent through the "data-parent" attribute and if there is no data parent then that attribute is -1.  If this is always the case, the code at the fiddle below should work.

```
var events = $('input[name="event-type[]"]');

$(events).each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-parent') != -1) {
        $(this).on('click',function() {
            var subBoxChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
            var subBoxes = $('input[data-parent="' + $(this).attr('data-parent') + '"]');

            $(subBoxes).each(function(index,element) {
                subBoxChecked = subBoxChecked || $(element).prop('checked');
            });

            $('input[value="' + $(this).attr('data-parent') + '"]').prop('checked',subBoxChecked);
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apandit/eqsg8kte/

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using jQuery, take a look at this:

```js
//all the child checkboxes have a parent value refering

//first append a click to all
//exclude data parent with -1.
$(document).ready(function(){
   //using a css-selector here with the a NOT comparison.
   $("input[data-parent!='-1']").click(function(){
       //here again a css-selector: check if the value matches the parent, then set it to checked.
       $("input[value='"+$(this).attr("data-parent")+"']").prop("checked", true);
       
   });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wpt-form-set wpt-form-set-checkboxes wpt-form-set-checkboxes-event-type" data-level="0">
  <li class="tax-corporate-events tax-event-type-52">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-30-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-30-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="52" data-parent="-1" data-value="CORPORATE EVENTS"
    class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
    <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-30-1438779193">CORPORATE EVENTS</label>
  </li>

  <li class="tax-children-of-52">
    <ul class="wpt-form-set-children wpt-form-set-children-level-1" data-level="1">
      <li class="tax-after-dinner-shows tax-event-type-87">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-31-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-31-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="87" data-parent="52" data-value="AFTER DINNER SHOWS"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-31-1438779193">AFTER DINNER SHOWS</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-award-ceremonies tax-event-type-92">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-32-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-32-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="92" data-parent="52" data-value="AWARD CEREMONIES"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-32-1438779193">AWARD CEREMONIES</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-background-music tax-event-type-86">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-33-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-33-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="86" data-parent="52" data-value="BACKGROUND MUSIC"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-33-1438779193">BACKGROUND MUSIC</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-comperes tax-event-type-91">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-34-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-34-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="91" data-parent="52" data-value="COMPERES"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-34-1438779193">COMPERES</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-dance-the-night-away tax-event-type-89">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-35-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-35-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="89" data-parent="52" data-value="DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-35-1438779193">DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-exhibitions tax-event-type-84">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-36-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-36-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="84" data-parent="52" data-value="EXHIBITIONS"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-36-1438779193">EXHIBITIONS</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-mix-mingle tax-event-type-90">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-37-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-37-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="90" data-parent="52" data-value="MIX &amp; MINGLE"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-37-1438779193">MIX &amp; MINGLE</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-product-launches tax-event-type-85">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-38-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-38-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="85" data-parent="52" data-value="PRODUCT LAUNCHES"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-38-1438779193">PRODUCT LAUNCHES</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-wow-factor tax-event-type-88">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-39-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-39-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="88" data-parent="52" data-value="WOW FACTOR"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-39-1438779193">WOW FACTOR</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="tax-private-parties tax-event-type-83">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-40-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-40-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="83" data-parent="-1" data-value="PRIVATE PARTIES"
    class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
    <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-40-1438779193">PRIVATE PARTIES</label>
  </li>

  <li class="tax-children-of-83">
    <ul class="wpt-form-set-children wpt-form-set-children-level-1" data-level="1">
      <li class="tax-chill-out tax-event-type-101">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-41-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-41-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="101" data-parent="83" data-value="CHILL OUT"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-41-1438779193">CHILL OUT</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-party-band tax-event-type-99">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-42-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-42-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="99" data-parent="83" data-value="PARTY BAND"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-42-1438779193">PARTY BAND</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-tribute-theme tax-event-type-98">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-43-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-43-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="98" data-parent="83" data-value="TRIBUTE THEME"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-43-1438779193">TRIBUTE THEME</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-walk-around-acts tax-event-type-102">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-44-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-44-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="102" data-parent="83" data-value="WALK AROUND ACTS"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-44-1438779193">WALK AROUND ACTS</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-wow-factor tax-event-type-100">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-45-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-45-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="100" data-parent="83" data-value="WOW FACTOR"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-45-1438779193">WOW FACTOR</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="tax-wedding tax-event-type-53">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-46-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-46-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="53" data-parent="-1" data-value="WEDDING"
    class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
    <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-46-1438779193">WEDDING</label>
  </li>

  <li class="tax-children-of-53">
    <ul class="wpt-form-set-children wpt-form-set-children-level-1" data-level="1">
      <li class="tax-ceremony tax-event-type-93">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-47-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-47-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="93" data-parent="53" data-value="CEREMONY"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-47-1438779193">CEREMONY</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-drinks-reception tax-event-type-94">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-48-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-48-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="94" data-parent="53" data-value="DRINKS RECEPTION"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-48-1438779193">DRINKS RECEPTION</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-evening-party tax-event-type-95">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-49-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-49-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="95" data-parent="53" data-value="EVENING PARTY"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-49-1438779193">EVENING PARTY</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-mix-mingle tax-event-type-97">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-50-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-50-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="97" data-parent="53" data-value="MIX &amp; MINGLE"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-50-1438779193">MIX &amp; MINGLE</label>
      </li>

      <li class="tax-sangeet tax-event-type-96">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-51-1438779193" name="event-type[]" data-wpt-type="checkbox" data-wpt-id="cred_form_6568_1_cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-51-1438779193" data-wpt-name="event-type[]" value="96" data-parent="53" data-value="SANGEET"
        class="wpt-form-checkbox form-checkbox checkbox">
        <label class="wpt-form-label wpt-form-checkbox-label" for="cred_form_6568_1-checkbox-51-1438779193">SANGEET</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the basic of the code. You have to work on it further. But it shows how you can manipulate the DOM with the data you have.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @Nick My answer below contains logic to check/uncheck based on the condition of the children.  Similar uncheck logic can be added to the parent so it will uncheck all the children check boxes if the parent is unchecked.

Comment: @apandit, nice work, but Stack Overflow isn't a "seek a coder that can do my whole project" website. The OP wanted to be guided into the right direction on how he could manipulate a DOM he didn't control.